# Allowable maximum size of data that goes along with output files in setup project for a windows form application using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, setup-project

I am working on a windows form application using C# and  have about 5 -10gb SWF files that are tied in to my windows form application. When I try to build these files along with the project output in setup project, Visual Studio Team system throws me an error "Not enough memory storage available". I am running this on a 32bit OS with 2 gigs ram.

My understanding is that you cannot exceed your RAM memory space, if so is there any way to fit in more than 4gb data in your set up project. I have also tried CAB files to no avail. I am looking into memory resource which calls for serialization of the data. If you have any idea please do help, thanks

Comment: Who wants 10 gigs of Flash crap installed on their system?

Comment: You may need to use a full installer package like InstallShield to get this to work.

Comment: well 10gigs of flash is actually educational content in flash format. The reason it is tied to the application is to encrypt the files and meant to be used over a certain period by the end client

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how is the swf-files tied to your application? Maybe you can split your project file, to get a work-around?

--Jocke

Comment: My winform application embeds a SWF player to play those files. It also provides security, encrypts those files and generates product key. I did find a work around which is not split into CAB or package within MSI but to package as uncompressed files. The Release folder is huge but it works for now. I am trying to use WIX to burn the DVD but failing, so if you know any way in .NET to burn multiple CD/DVD with prompt for insert new CD, please do let me know. Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Ok, sounds like a good enought work-around! Don't have too much experience with burning DVDs from .NET, but this thread might point you in the right direction! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441227/how-to-burn-video-dvd-from-c